# I'm trying to implement a searchable List View that in a Tab Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, tabs, adapter

I'm trying to implement a searchable List View  that in a Tab Activity. Thus Home Page Have 3 tab and in 1st tab i need a list view with a search edit text box.The following code work separately as Tab functionality and List view with Search. when i combine these i got error in the line

adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products); show add on demand static package which remove the R  only.

I don't know how to go about this. Help would be appreciated.

```
    package com.artificers.subin.inspection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by Subin on 13-10-2015.
 */
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {

    // List view
    private ListView lv;

    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;


    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_view, container, false);

        // Listview Data
        String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE",
                "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800",
                "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};

        lv = (ListView) V.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        inputSearch = (EditText) V.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        // Adding items to listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                Tab1Fragment.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        return V;
    }


}
```

Comment: Please add the error's trace

Comment: Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(com.artificers.subin.inspection.Tab1Fragment, int, int, java.lang.String[])'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using "this" as the context param in the ArrayAdapter constructor but a Fragment is not a subclass of Context.

So, in your case, you have to use one of the next solutions:

1º - Getting the parent activity:

```
 // Adding items to listview
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

2º - Getting the context:

```
 // Adding items to listview
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Its get error while i change Fragment to FragmentActivity

Comment: Fragment and FragmentActivity aren't subclases of the same object. A Fragment isn't a subclass of Context, so to use the context in it you have to use getContext() or getActivity(). A FragmentActivity isn't a Fragment, it is a subclass of Activity that could contain Fragments, so in a FragmentActivity you couldn't use "getActivity()"  nor "getContext()", you have to use "this".